# Merge strings in outfile

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

i m stuck to merge two variable in 1 file output 
Here is the example of my File:

```
   cat  $ line 
    "Product ID";"Product Name";"Price";"Description"
    "310";"Ball;"30";"Some"
```

My code

```
while read line IFS=';' read pid pname price desc <<< $line
numn=0
If [ condition ]
((num++)
 output_filename=comb/"$(echo $pid| tr -d '"').json3"
else
fi
```

The result of this file is  "310.json3"
What i  need ?

```
output_filename=comb/"$(echo $pid + ($num) | tr -d '"').json3"

Output= 310(1).json3
```

Comment: is `line` a file with 2 lines, the first of which is a description ? What must the output file look like exactly given that two lines of input? I find the task unclear and the bash syntax (e.g. for `if`) is also wrong. Seems like a job for awk to me.

Comment: this is a example   the file contain  500 product id. 
I need to merge the  output file whit the name  of $ pid  &  $num.
The bash  script  work well. 
I can save the file  whit the $pid but i cant  whit $pid(num)
Thx

Comment: where does the `num` come from? There is a `numn` which is reset to 0 for every line? The script you posted makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

To make the filename you could do

```
output_filename=$(printf "comb/%u(%u).json3" $pid $num)
```

if that is your main problem..

Comment: Henno  your solution no work well  because i have this  `| tr -d '"'` to delete the " ".
Where put this comand in yours ? thx

Comment: I fix this problem  
Whit this solution 
`pid=$(echo $pid | tr -d '"')`